# Wake On Lan no longer works

Tags: networking, windows-10, dd-wrt, windows-10-upgrade, wake-on-lan

Sometime in the past month WoL has stopped working for me. I downloaded a program called Wake On Lan Monitor and when i start with Port 9 and run the command on my router to turn my PC on, it successfully receives the packet, however, when I have my PC off and run the command, it does not turn on the PC.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSJ5v.png) are my NIC's WoL settings.

I upgraded my NIC Driver to the latest version but the issue still persists.

My PC recently installed the Windows 10 Creators Update and I recently upgraded the version of DD-WRT on my router to r33215 so I am not sure which of these 2 caused the issue (if its one of them).

What could the issue be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wake on Lan has suddenly stopped working](https://superuser.com/questions/1251200/wake-on-lan-has-suddenly-stopped-working)

Comment: Check your bios settings.

Answer (score 2):

In the power option, check that "fast startup" (or something like that ("Activer le démarrage rapide" in French)) is **un-checked**.
One of my laptop upgraded to Windows 10 could not wake-on-lan if this option is active.